# php print xml data returned from api call- failed

Tags: php, xml, printing

```
$response = sendRequest($curl, doCreateDB($domainid, $dbname, $dbtype));                                        

$responseXml = parseResponse($response);


function parseResponse($response_string)
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response_string);
    if (!is_a($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement'))
        throw new ApiRequestException("Cannot parse server response: {$response_string}");
    return $xml;
}
```

### full output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.5.0.0
        )

    [database] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [add-db] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [status] => error
                            [errcode] => 1007
                            [errtext] => Database with requested name already exists
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Final output at above. Then I want to get specific node's value.
Eg: i want to get status node.

I tried a few ways, but can't seems to print out the specific data.

```
echo $responseXml->database->{add-db}->result->status; // (nothing come out)
```

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $responseXml->database->{'add-db'}->result->status;
```

Note the single quotes to select a hyphenated array item: {'...'}.

Comment: thank you for your syntax. It works perfectly after adding quote to the hypernated array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo (string)$responseXml->database->{add-db}->result->status;
```

Comment: not working. When I print the whole code, output without any problem. When only need to print value in specific node, nothing come out.